# Unable to ping/ connect to external addresses

Tags: networking, internet

I own a raspberry pi 3b+ which has a static ip address and local domain. I am able to see it and access it via my local network. I can telnet and ping it successfully and can SSH to it successfully within the local network.

My problem lies when trying to access external address/ domains from within the PI itself... while I am experiencing slow ping times to popular sites such as facebook.com and google.com. PINGS seem to timeout when trying to ping github.com and sohh.com. I also cannot seem to successfully `apt-get update` it

The following scenarios are also true:-

1. I can conduct the same ping scenarios successfully from another device on the same network as the PI
2. The pi is connected via eth0 ethernet port( my wlan/ wifi seems to have malfunction)
3. I was able to accomplish these tasks a couple of days ago before I had a power outage.

Here is an output from a ping test from the PI

> PING google.com(mia07s49-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e))
> 56 data bytes 64 bytes from mia07s49-in-x0e.1e100.net

> (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=114 time=45.4 ms 64 bytes
> from mia07s49-in-x0e.1e100.net

> (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=114 time=44.9 ms 64 bytes from mia07s49-in-x0e.1e100.net
> (2607:f8b0:4008:803::200e): icmp_seq=3 ttl=114 time=45.2 ms

Here is another test

> PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
> --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
> 100 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1075ms

Here is a curl test

> curl https://api.github.com
> curl: (7) Failed to connect to api.github.com port 443: Connection timed out

Here is another test

> ssh -vT github.com OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2, OpenSSL 1.1.1d
> 10 Sep 2019
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

> debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * debug1:

> Connecting to github.com [140.82.114.3] port 22. debug1: connect to

> address 140.82.114.3 port 22: Connection timed out ssh: connect to

> host github.com port 22: Connection timed out

I am able to

`sudo host -t ns github.com`

```
> github.com name server dns2.p08.nsone.net.
> github.com name server ns-1283.awsdns-32.org. 
> github.com name server dns1.p08.nsone.net.
> github.com name server ns-421.awsdns-52.com.
> github.com name server ns-520.awsdns-01.net. 
> github.com name server dns4.p08.nsone.net. 
> github.com name server ns-1707.awsdns-21.co.uk.
> github.com name server dns3.p08.nsone.net.
```

Comment: is the static IP a "private" IP in the same subnetwork as your router (something like 192.168.1.100)? I mean, it looks like ipv6 works, because you probably didn't mess around with that, but ipv4 - what is the static IP you assigned to the pi and how did you attempt it

Comment: Also, make your output readable, at the moment it's not

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes! the private ip was a subnetwork from router mapping ip to mac address and then setting the ip to the eth0 interface from raspberry pi.

Comment: I have since removed the static ip address mapping

Comment: right, so what's your IP address now, and what is the output of `ip route`

Comment: @JaromandaX default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.100.73 metric 202